# Lemon tree lost all its leaves

Tags: trees, leaves, lemons

My lemon tree lost all its leaves a while ago. I was hoping it would recover but I’m not sure anymore. I’m a little inexperienced with taking care of plants but I’ve scraped a bit of bark off the bottom of the tree and the inside layer still has moisture. 
I’m not really sure whether it’s alive or not and if it is what to do?

Comment: Can you add some  more info please - is the tree in or outdoors? If   indoors, is it there  year round, or does it go outside in the summer? How long have you had it? What part of the world are you in? and finally, can you add a photo please